# php Getting value from standalone javascript

Tags: php, curl

I'm using curl to get a remote page.. I have a local js file.. Its called `main.js`.

I want to execute that js file on that curl page.

My `main.js` file outputs the result as `JSON` string.

I would like to assign that string in a php variable. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To execute JavaScript you need a JavaScript engine. You can do this in a headless browser like [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/),or you can try with [v8 js extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php) for PHP

Answer (score 0):

Try

1) In the main.js

```
`myobj = new Array();
 myobj["field1"] = field1; 
 myobj["field2"] = $("#field2").val();
 myobj["field3"] = $("#field3").val();
 myobj["field4"] = field4; `
```

field1 and field 4 if you have the value directly and field2 and field 3 if it comes from a html form. Now put it

```
`FormArray(myobj);
 var data = JSON.stringify($("#form").serializeObject());`
```

Now you need to call the php function that is going to receive the data. Ye it can be confused so it is a great method.

```
`$.ajax({
        url:    'yourphpfile.php?,
        data:   {
            module: 'path',
            datos:  data, // Your data flying to php here
        },
        async:      false,
        type:       'POST',
        success:    function(html){

        }`
```

Now in yourphpfile.php that is going to receive the data put

```
 `$datos = json_decode($datos);
  $field1 = $datos->field1;
  $field2 = $datos->field2
  $field3 = $datos->field3
  $field4 = $datos->field4`
```

Hope it help you!!